# How to Properly Create SVN-Tag with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tagging

I'm having troubles to understand how to create a tag with TortoiseSVN. This is what the dialogue usually looks like when I open it from the "Log Messages"-browser in TortoiseSVN before I click "OK":

[image]

The "Specific revision in repository" is always selected even though I opened the dialogue on the latest revision, so 696 in this case is the latest there is.

[The documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) says this:

> Subversion does not have special commands for branching or tagging, but uses so-called “cheap copies” instead. Cheap copies are similar to hard links in Unix, which means that instead of making a complete copy in the repository, an internal link is created, pointing to a specific tree/revision. As a result **branches and tags are very quick to create**, and take up almost no extra space in the repository.

However, doing that takes longer and longer with every tag I create, the last time it took about 30 minutes. Also the paths in the `trunk`-directory get longer and longer:

```
C:\workspaces\projects\myproject\tags\Release_2020_07\tags\Release_2020_06\tags\Release_2020_05\tags\Release_2020_04\tags\Release_2020_03\tags\Release_2020_02\tags\Release_2020-03-12
```

IMHO, this can't be right.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I really do this?
2. How do I get rid of those subdirectories in case that is an option?

My goal is to have that quick tagging experience as lined out in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting revision 696 pre-selected because you're launching the dialogue from the SVN log, thus TortoiseSVN assumes you want to create the branch from an older revision. If want to branch HEAD revision you can create the branch right from a working copy (*TortoiseSVN/ Branch/tag* context menu) or from the Repo-browser (*Copy to* context menu).

You're also creating the branch inside the original folder. This is (seriously) not different from regular folders in your computer. If you copy `C:\Data` into `C:\Data\Data` you'll get an increasingly larger duplicated folder structure. The typical SVN layout goes like:

```
- trunk
- tags
- branches
    - branch1
    - branch2
    - branch3
```

... and a branch creation would look like this:

[image: Screen-shot]

In particular, please note that target path (`/branches/1.x`) is not contained in source path (`/trunk`). In your case, source path (`/`) also contains target path.

Comment: Well, I also have the various tags as subdirectories of the `tags`-directory, but as lined out in my question they also appear as subdirectories of their various predecessors, which seems odd. -- So I should create tags with "TortoiseSVN - Branch/tag" rather than from the message log? The dialogue doesn't look that much different, though. Or should I simply click the "HEAD revision in the repository"? Do you maybe have an answer to my second How-question?

Comment: You've redacted the path component after `/svn/` so I assumed it's the same in source and target URLs (please correct me if I'm wrong) and that should be your biggest issue. The dialogue is basically the same, but you can't use a working copy as source if not launched from a working copy and also some default values differ.

Comment: Yes, they are the same. So I just tried that with "TortoiseSVN - Branch/tag" and HEAD selected. It was faster, but the server still creates the existing tags in the new tag, so now I have "https://.../svn/.../tags/Release_2020_08/tags/Release_2020_07/tags/" and so forth. I'm currently updating my local directory and it downloads all that again. So it's still the same mess IMHO.

Comment: Please disregard my comment about the redacted fragment (I didn't notice it's meant to be the repository name). I've added a picture that hopefully clarifies it all. Also, the dialogue is totally the same, just default values change. Use it from wherever you find it easier. I suspect you want to create branches but you don't have a separate trunk and all your code is in the repository root.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but this question is about tags and not branches . I don't know SVN enough, somebody told me that tags are branches, though. So I'm in the default branch and simply want to tag the revision. If to SVN it really means to copy the entire repository every time including what it had copied with a previous tag, SVN is even worse than I thought it was... Let's not rant, though :) BTW, it's still updating my local repo :( That'll take a week in five revisions...

Comment: In Subversion everything is a directory, the terms "branch" and "tag" are nothing but conventions. Forget about SVN right now and imagine you have your code like `C:\Projects\Acme\main.c` and you decide to create `C:\Projects\Acme\Next\main.c`. If you copy `C:\Projects` into `C:\Projects\Acme` several times, you'll end up with several nested copies of the same files. What you really want is `C:\Projects\Acme\Current\main.c` and  `C:\Projects\Acme\Next\main.c`.

Comment: OK, I got that part. So basically you tell me that this is how it/SVN works, there is no way around it and tagging + updates may take weeks soon because of the amount of data? My current update is still running and I don't see an end...

Comment: No, that isn't what I'm saying at all. Subversion works fine but you're using it wrong. A branch takes a breeze to create and hardly uses additional storage. Every time you create a branch you add new files to it, all previous copies of the project. That's crazy. It's like running `type foo.txt >> foo.txt` in sequence: you'll eventually fill your storage.

Comment: OK, so this leads us to my second question: how do I get rid of that?

Comment: Do you have a `trunk` directory?

Comment: Yes. I have `.svn`, `branches` (empty), `tags` and `trunk`.

Comment: Then change **From WD / URL** from `https://example.com/svn/repository_name` to `https://example.com/svn/repository_name/trunk`.

Comment: I also suggest you check out a different working copy for `trunk`. Right now, you have the complete repository in a single working copy and the `tags` directory alone is huge. Cheap copies apply to repository storage, not network transfer or local disk.

Comment: Currently I'm checking out the entire repo again. I took a look already what the dialogue would look like for creating a tag and the Repository-section there looks like my screenshot, i.e. I don't have the ".../trunk"-path in the "From WC / URL"-field. Maybe there's something completely wrong with the repo to begin with. Should I use "TortoiseSVN - Switch" or "TortoiseSVN - Relocate" for that?

Comment: The **From WC / URL** field is populated according to the location in your working copy where you right-click to launch TortoiseSVN. If you click on the root you'll get the root. You need to click on `trunk`.

Comment: Ah, OK! Now I know what my actual mistake was (you may have tried to tell me that 100 times by now...). The same is true for opening the log messages. Thanks for that info! -- When opened from `trunk` I'm now missing the tags that I've created which makes sense given all the previous comments. Can I remove those wrong "global" tags somehow and create the correct tags for the `trunk` as it should be?

Comment: Since your current working copy includes the complete repository, you can just remove them locally and commit changes. It's worth noting though that repository keeps the entire history so you won't get server storage back—perhaps it isn't a big deal anyway.

Comment: After it took about two days to remove and commit those directories in `tags` I created the tags on the `trunk`-directory, which really was very fast. The commit log says it did it (the "Copy from path" is now `/trunk`), but I the `branches`- and `tags`-directories are now empty. I don't know if it's supposed to be like that.